# Does React native's FlatList detect if there is more to scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of some items and I want to be sure that the user knows that he is able to scroll in that list so I wanted to implement an arrow indicating that you can scroll down so,

Is there a prop in the FlatList component that detects if you have reached the end or if there is more to scroll in react native?

Comment: It does thank you so much!